# Does R `unique` always return values in same order?

Tags: r, unique

Stupid example:

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS, each=2), value=1:52)
res <- unlist(lapply(unique(df$group), function(x) mean(subset(df, group==x)$value)))
names(res) <- unique(df$group)
```

Will `res` always be?

```
   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P 
 1.5  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5 13.5 15.5 17.5 19.5 21.5 23.5 25.5 27.5 29.5 31.5 
   Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z 
33.5 35.5 37.5 39.5 41.5 43.5 45.5 47.5 49.5 51.5
```

Or will it ever happen that the means calculated on line 2 won't match up to the names on line 3? I guess it depends on the underlying implementation of `unique` in the R base, but I'm not sure where to find that.

Comment: I believe it returns them in the order they appear in the original vector, but the documentation doesn't _explicitly_ promise this (though it sort of hints at it) so if you're willing to assume a small amount of risk you could assume that I suppose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to `?unique`:

> ‘unique’ returns a vector, data frame or array like ‘x’ but with
>        duplicate elements/rows removed.

This description gives you a complete description of the ordering -- it will be in the same order as the order of the *first* unique elements.  (I guess I don't see the wiggle room that @joran sees for a different ordering.) For example,

```
unique(c("B","B","A","C","C","C","B","A"))
```

will result in

```
[1] "B" "A" "C"
```

I believe `unique(x)` will in general be identical to (but more efficient than)

```
x[!duplicated(x)]
```

If you want to look at the internal code, see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/unique.c): the moving parts are something like

```
k = 0;
switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
case LGLSXP:
case INTSXP:
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (LOGICAL(dup)[i] == 0)
    INTEGER(ans)[k++] = INTEGER(x)[i];
break;
```

i.e., the internal representation is exactly what I said, that it goes through the vector sequentially and fills in non-duplicated elements. Since ordering isn't explicitly guaranteed in the documentation it is *theoretically* possible that this implementation could change in the future, but it is almost vanishingly unlikely.

For what you're trying to do there are simpler R idioms

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS, each=2), value=1:52)
a1 <- aggregate(df$value,list(df$group),mean)
```

This returns a two-column data frame, so you can use

```
setNames(a1[,2],a1[,1])
```

to convert it to your format.  Or

```
library(plyr)
unlist(daply(df,"group",summarise,val=mean(value)))
```

Comment: Well, technically, a sorted list of unique elements _is_ "like" x, but with duplicate elements removed. ;)

Comment: I guess I interpret the documentation same as @joran - that R doesn't explicitly promise to return them FIFO. Group consensus is good enough for me!

Answer (score 3):

R will return a sorted vector if unique is called on a RasterLayer object.

```
example <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 100, ymn = 0, ymx = 100, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
example[] <- sample(x <- 1:100, 10000, replace = TRUE)

plot(example)

vals <- values(example)[x]
identical(vals, x)

uniques <- unique(example)
identical(uniques, x)
```

The values should (very likely) not be identical to the ordered vector, but unique values will always be identical to the ordered vector.

Otherwise, the previous answers are correct that R will return a vector of the order that the non-duplicates appeared.